# Can I uniquely identify DVDR(W)(+/-) medium from .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, cddvd

I would like identify DVDR mediums from .NET code. It's possible and how?

Some kind of library, which call Windows API.

**UPDATE**

I have lot of DVDRs and I need to identify each of them, but not depends on content or disk name. Some kind of serial number of each DVDRs, which DVDR get in factory.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the [IMAPI v2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.

Once you have the correct references within your .NET project, along with the various enums that are defined within that API (and there's quite a few of them!), the code is relatively straightforward.  Something like (pseudo-code):

```
IDiscRecorder2 discRecorder = (IDiscRecorder2)[*cd/dvd drive*];
discFormatData.Recorder = discRecorder;
IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE mediaType = discFormatData.CurrentPhysicalMediaType;
string mediaTypeString = GetMediaTypeString(mediaType);

where:
IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE is an enum such like:

public enum IMAPI_MEDIA_PHYSICAL_TYPE
{
    IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 0,
    IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_CDROM = 1,
    IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_CDR = 2,
    IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_CDRW = 3,
    IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_DVDROM = 4,
    IMAPI_MEDIA_TYPE_DVDRAM = 5,
    [not the complete enum...snipped for brevity!]
}

and the "GetMediaTypeString" function simply gives a friendly string
representation of the enum name.
```

There's a good article and sample project on the CodeProject website that demonstrates this fairly comprehensively:

[Burning and Erasing CD/DVD/Blu-ray Media with C# and IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx)

That project contains much more than just detecting the media type (hence the title!), but does contain code to effectively detect the media type prior to burning/erasing the media.

From the article:

> **Determining Media Type**
>
> To determine the media type and available space on the hard drive, you create a MsftDiscFormat2Data object and set the current recorder in the Recorder property. You can then get the media type from the IDiscFormat2Data CurrentPhysicalMediaType property.
>
> Once you have the media type, create a MsftFileSystemImage object and call the ChooseImageDefaultsForMediaType method with the media type.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this could article I found on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharpripper.aspx) could help?